# Kill process by pid with boost process

Tags: c++, boost, process, boost-process

I do want to kill a process I have a pid of, so my code is the following:

```cpp
pid_t pid = 28880;
boost::process::child process { pid };
std::cout << "Running: " << process.running() << "\n";
process.terminate();
```

I noticed though that running() always returns false (no matter what pid I take) and based on the source code then terminate isn't even called.

Digging a little bit deeper it seem to be the linux function `waitpid` is called. And it always returns -1 (which means some error has occured, rather than 0, which would mean: Yes the process is still running).

WIFSIGNALED return 1 and WTERMSIG returns 5.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost process is a library for the *execution* (and manipulation) of child processes. Yours is not (necesarily) a child process, and not created by boost.

Indeed `running()` doesn't work unless the process is attached. Using that constructor by definition results in a detached process.

> This leaves the interesting question why this constructor exists, but let's focus on the question.

Detached processes cannot be joined or terminated.

The `terminate()` call is a no-op.

I would suggest writing the logic yourself - the code is not that complicated (POSIX [`kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) or [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)).

If you want you can **cheat** by using implementation details from the library:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bp = boost::process;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (std::string_view arg : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        bp::child::child_handle pid{std::atoi(arg.data())};
        std::cout << "pid " << pid.id();

        std::error_code ec;
        bp::detail::api::terminate(pid, ec);
        std::cout << " killed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

With e.g.

```
cat &
./sotest $!
```

Prints

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already wondered that the process is detached (noticed that as well). Why can't it be attached? 
I will try your "cheat" as I wanted boost for a cross platform solution in the first place. Is there any reason why boost offers no api for querying processes and stuff like that (neither does Qt).

Comment: Your cheat works! The process I try to kill is in fact created by boost, but detached. To give some context: I write a setup / teardown script for my database & server in order to run tests. CMake requires for this that the setup script actually finishes (This setup thing is a ctest feature).
So I start a child process with boost, write down the pid in a file, detach it. Then run my tests and in teardown I read the pid in and kill the process. 
If you have any better idea / any library that is actually suited for that task, I would be happy to hear it!

Comment: Like I said, process control isn't what Boost Process is for. What's wrong with just sending the signal using the APIs mentioned? The fact that the process was "created by boost process" is irrelevant when the process was created _by another process_ :)